# Question asking pipeline for Huggingface transformers

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Huggingface tranformers has a pipeline for question answering tuning on the Squad dataset.

What would I need to do to develop a pipeline for a question asking pipeline? This would use the context, question and answer to generate questions with answers from a context. Are there any examples for creating new hunggingface pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

Pipelines can simply be treated as a wrapper around pre-trained models. In this case, you could perform fine-tuning/pre-training in the same way as existing example scripts such as [`run_squad`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/run_squad.py). You can of course

An example on how to load custom checkpoint models is given on the [HuggingFace website](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html) (slightly modified here):

```py
from transformers import pipeline

# Question answering pipeline, specifying the checkpoint identifier
pipeline('question-answering', model='distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad', tokenizer='bert-base-cased')
```

If your pipeline differs from existing options to a point where you indeed need to implement a new pipeline class, then I would suggest to look at the [respective implementation](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/pipelines.py#L875). Specifically, most models do "nothing more" than to neatly wrap the tokenization step on pre-trained models, and calling the correct parameters on the `model.forward` function. This is probably as concise as an example as you will currently (version 2.8) find, since the feature is still relatively new.

I hope all the pointers helped to get you started!