# What features are used in the default transformers pipeline?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm looking [here at the feature extraction pipeline](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#featureextractionpipeline).

I initialize with the following:

```
from transformers import pipeline 
pipe = pipeline("feature-extraction") 
features = pipe("test")
```

And I get a bunch of features.  What model is this using by default?  How can I initialize this pipeline to use a particular pre-trained model?

```
len(features)
1
>>> features
[[[0.4122459590435028, 0.10175584256649017, 0.09342928230762482, -0.3119196593761444, -0.3226662278175354, -0.16414110362529755, 0.06356583535671234, -0.03167172893881798, -0.010002809576690197, -1.1153486967086792, -0.3304346203804016, 0.1727224737405777, -0.0904250368475914, -0.04243310168385506, -0.4745883047580719, 0.09118127077817917, 0.4240476191043854, 0.2237153798341751, 0.12108077108860016, -0.16883963346481323, 0.055300742387771606, -0.07225772738456726, 0.4521999955177307, -0.31655701994895935, 0.05917530879378319, -0.0343029648065567, 0.4157347083091736, 0.10791877657175064, -0
...etc
```

While the document tells me:

> All models may be used for this pipeline. See a list of all models, including community-contributed models on huggingface.co/models.

It's not clear to me where to initialize the models in this link.  The API is very terse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you have rightly stated, the `pipelines` documentation is rather sparse.
However, the source code specifies which models are used by default, see [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/pipelines.py#L2362). Specifically, the model is `distilbert-base-cased`.

For a way to use models, see a related answer by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132448/question-asking-pipeline-for-huggingface-transformers/61136242#61136242). You can simply specifiy the `model` and `tokenizer` parameters like this:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

# Question answering pipeline, specifying the checkpoint identifier
pipeline('feature-extraction', model='bert-base-cased', tokenizer='bert-base-cased')
```

Comment: Thanks. What exactly is the return value of this?  The shape doesn't make sense to me:
`pl = pipeline('feature-extraction', model='bert-base-cased', tokenizer='bert-base-cased')x = pl("this is a sentence")

len(x)
1
len(x[0])
6
`

Comment: It's a list of the hidden state vectors. If you inspect the length of `x[0][0]`, it is 768, which is the corresponding dimension of the hidden states. The first dimension is the number of samples (in your case, just one), the second is the number of extracted subwords after tokenization (which is why there are more than the number of words in the sentence). See the docstring of the forward pass [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/pipelines.py#L704)