# How to load transformers pipeline from folder?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

According to [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines) `pipeline` provides an interface to save a pretrained pipeline locally with a `save_pretrained` method. When I use it, I see a folder created with a bunch of json and bin files presumably for the tokenizer and the model.

But the documentation does not specify a load method. How does one initialize a `pipeline` using a locally saved pipeline?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently the default initialization works with local folders as well. So one can download a model like this:

```
pipe = pipeline("text-classification")
pipe.save_pretrained("my_local_path")
```

And later load it like

```
pipe = pipeline("text-classification", model = "my_local_path")
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Does it also automatically load the correct tokenizer, even if you technically only specify the `model`?

Comment: The folder contains a `tokenizer.json` which I assume gets loaded automatically. I wonder if it loads a default tokenizer though

Answer (score 9):

If you read the specification for `save_pretrained`, it simply states that it

> Save[s] the pipeline’s **model and tokenizer**.

I've also given a slightly related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132448/question-asking-pipeline-for-huggingface-transformers) on how custom models and tokenizers can be loaded. Essentially, you can simply specify the specific models/paths in the `pipeline`:

```py
from transformers import pipeline, AutoModel, AutoTokenizer

# Replace with your custom model of choice
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('/path/to/your/model')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('/path/to/your/tokenizer')

pipe = pipeline(task='summarization',  # replace with whatever task you have
                model=model,
                tokenizer=tokenizer)
```

Comment: We should load our model using `AutoModel.from_pretrained` instead of `AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained` right?

Comment: Of course, you are right. Fixed in the answer!